# capture the parameter and value from multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, grep, find

we have the following 100-1000 files under `/var/place` folder

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-10.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-11.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-12.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-13.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-14.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-15.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-16.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-17.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-18.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   261 Dec 24 22:52 total_machines-19.json
```

.
.

each file ( `total_machines_rhel-xx.json` ) look like this ( while topic value could be diff )

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "partitions": [
    {
      "topic": "total_machines_rhel",
      "partition": 10,
      "replicas": [
        1001,
        1003,
        1004
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

how to print the topic **value** name for all this files

expected results

```
total_machines-10.json topic=total_machines_rhel
total_machines-11.json topic=total_machines_fedora
total_machines-12.json topic=total_machines_aix
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `jq` version 1.5+

```
jq -r '.partitions[] | "\(input_filename) topic=\(.topic)"' total_machines-*.json
```

---

With Perl's JSON module:

```
perl -MJSON -0777 -nE '
  $h = decode_json($_); say "$ARGV topic=$h->{partitions}[0]{topic}"
' total_machines-*.json
```

---

With [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html), using an out-of-stream array indexed by the current filename. *Note that Miller currently flattens JSON arrays into integer-keyed maps, but since your files only have a single element in each `partitions` array that's not a serious limitation in this case - it's really no worse than relying on the data being in element `[0]` in the perl version.*

```
mlr --ijson --onidx put -S -q '
  @value[FILENAME] = "topic=".${partitions:0:topic}; end {emit @value, "a"}
' total_machines-*.json
```